# How to get security relevant commits in a git repository?

Tags: git, security, logging, grep, commit

I'm just thinking how best to output security related git commits using git log.

Maybe:

```
git log all --grep='security'
```

I would be grateful for any better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %aI | %s%d [%an]' | grep -i "security"
```

should list all the commits with the keyword "security" in it.

I hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, simple but very good solution!

Comment: @Roland I'm glad it helped! :)